# Removing decimal point from number

Tags: php

I am looking to convert a decimal string, so it outputs without the decimal.

The following works correctly, outputting '13495' as an INT.

```
$current_total = intval(str_replace(".","","134.95"));
```

Is there any reason why this method shouldn't be used?

Comment: No reason why not. Depends on what you want to use it for.

Comment: how many decimal places are you working with?

Comment: @Will 2 decimal places.

Comment: $newTotal = $current_total * 100;

Comment: @Will Thanks. I tried this already and it created a float, rather than an INT

Comment: if is need to be INT, you need add `(int)` so it should be `$newTotal = (int) ($current_total * 100);` otherwise it will be still decimal/float data type.

Comment: @Hekimen This returns '13400', not '13495' - Any ideas?

Comment: yea i forgot brackets, already edited ;)

Comment: @Hekimen Thanks, but this outputs '13494', instead of '13495'.

Comment: Apparently here is problem with float numbers, you can read more about this here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), to my knowledge PHP don't have decimal data type which solve this problem, so i guess in your case will be better to stick with your code and work with numbers as with strings.